# iOS CoreLocation: Turn it off after position was found or let it run

Tags: ios, core-location, battery

I build a gps tracker which takes the current position every 20 seconds or if the device rotates more than xx °.

Now I'm not sure what's the best solution for saving battery energy:

1) Stop CoreLocation service after I got a position and turn it on if the timer expires

2) Don't turn off CoreLocation service while tracking

So, does turn the service on and off consumes more battery power than do not turn it off (during tracking)?

Answer (score 0):

You should turn it off when you are not tracking. But you should not alternate between on and off while tracking.

If your interval was 3-4x longer I would say turn it off in between.